# Unable to install Firefox OS Simulator on Firefox WebIDE in Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-os

I can not install Firefox OS Simulator in Firefox (60.0.2 (64-bit) Mozilla Firefox for Linux Mint-1.0).

I am trying to install Firefox OS Simulator in Firefox WebIDE. I have Linux Mint 18 Sarah, MATE 64-bit.

[image: Firefox Web IDE]

[image: Firefox add]

Comment: I have the same problem..have you managed to solve it?

Comment: @ Idle Man , I have not a solution for Firefox to found.. but now when i will a Smartphone to simulate , i to do it With Chrome , in Chrome is there a Pluging the name "Mobile Browser Emulator" , you can Download it here , https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mobile-browser-emulator/lbofcampnkjmiomohpbaihdcbjhbfepf  , it is easy to work here a Video how working it.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVfrxv_JKCQ   and reminder that simulation to consume many Ram ......

Comment: I think i have to find a solution for you and me.. is there not many information about it maybe therefore have not found before it.. look under , i will explain it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry about my English.....

I found the solution for my Problem.... Firefox OS simulator  is not more supported . But there is gut Information ..., there is[Toggling Responsive Design Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode) , it work similar as Firefox OS simulator .You can open it above in Toolbar on **Tools** + 
**Web Development** + **Responsive Design Mode**  and it very easy to working.....
Und it use less resources as Mobile Browser Emulator from Chrome....

A Screenshot how to see it on a "Google Nexus 5"....
[Screenshot from "Google Nexus 5"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYCRs.png)